# How do I create a webpage that reports data on a local network?

Tags: matlab, d3.js, html

I need some advice and guidance with starting a project. I have a MATLAB program that outputs data into a JSON file and a folder of images. I would like to have a webpage accessible through a local network that visualizes this data. My input data is well defined and I will visualize the data using d3js, but I do not know the rest.

How to setup a webpage for a local network?

How do I create a webpage that will periodically check the contents of the JSON file and update the display with the latest data?

Comment: What are you asking for? How to set implement a periodical update? How to set up a webserver? How to connect it to matlab?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. How do I get a webpage to periodically update with the most recent file containing JSON data and the contents of a folder with images? How do I set up a webserver that computers on a local network can access? I was planning to connect this webpage to MATLAB by having MATLAB export updated JSON data and images using timer objects.